# Javascript replace several character including '/'

Tags: javascript, replace, character, reserved

Im using this snippet to replace several characters in a string.

```
var badwords = eval("/foo|bar|baz/ig");
var text="foo the bar!";
document.write(text.replace(badwords, "***"));
```

But one of the characters I want to replace is '/'. I assume it's not working because it's a reserved character in regular expressions, but how can I get it done then?

Thanks!

Comment: Where's the slash in your code?

Comment: As asked by Álvaro, seeing what you're really trying to do would help us avoid making up random examples and get you on your way quicker.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first of DON'T USE EVAL it's the most evil function ever and fully unnecessary here

```
var badwords = /foo|bar|baz/ig;
```

works just as well (or use the `new RegExp("foo|bar|baz","ig");` constructor)

and when you want to have a `/` in the regex and a `\` before the character you want to escape

```
var badwords = /\/foo|bar|baz/ig;
//or
var badwords = new RegExp("\\/foo|bar|baz","ig");//double escape to escape the backslash in the string like one has to do in java
```

Comment: Gerat, that's what I wanted to know to escape a character I have to put backslashes.
Also thanks for the advidce of not using eval

Answer (score 4):

You simply escape the "reserved" char in your RegExp:

```
var re = /abc\/def/;
```

You are probably having trouble with that because you are, for some reason, using a string as your RegExp and then evaling it...so odd.

```
var badwords = /foo|bar|baz/ig;
```

is all you need.

If you INISIST on using a string, then you have to escape your escape:

```
var badwords = eval( "/foo|ba\\/r|baz/ig" );
```

This gets a backslash through the JS interpreter to make it to the RegExp engine.

Comment: I'd give you +2 if I could. Because you didn't just answer the question but also provided some improvement to OP code.

Comment: For completeness: you can also `new RegExp("foo|bar|baz", "ig")` - https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions

Comment: You can, but I don't know why people do something like that unless they need to concat a string together to make a dynamic pattern. I never understand the use of constructor functions where a literal would work. Note to the OP, however, if you use the RegExp constructor, you're back to using a string so you need to double escape the backslash.